# Fixing an Or Statement With Variables

Tags: python

How would I change the below code so Python reads the list which is inside the two variables and then perform an action after that without reeving an error? My code:

```
bad = ['bad','terrible', 'dumb']
good = ['good','happy','awesome']
talk = raw_input("type:")
if (bad) in talk:
     print "I'm sorry to hear that :("
elif (good) in talk:
     print "That's good!"
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
bad = set(['bad','terrible', 'dumb'])
good = set(['good','happy','awesome'])
talk = raw_input("type:")
if bad & set(talk.lower().split()):
     print "I'm sorry to hear that :("
elif good & set(talk.lower().split()):
     print "That's good!"
```

Comment: That's an interesting but nice way of doing it.

Comment: You could set `talk = set(raw_input().lower().split())` to avoid calculating it twice if there's no intersection the first time.

Comment: Yeah i was thinking about doing that, and not sure about clarity of expression since this is an example.

Answer (score 3):

Does this get you what you want?

```
bad = ['bad','terrible', 'dumb']
good = ['good','happy','awesome']
talk = raw_input("type:")

talk_list = talk.lower().split()

is_bad = any(w in bad for w in talk_list)
is_good = any(w in good for w in talk_list)

if is_bad:
     print "I'm sorry to hear that :("
elif is_good:
     print "That's good!"
```

Comment: If he inputs "terrible and dumb", your solution will not catch it!

Comment: @aaronasterling:  The question was unclear on the first read.  I rewrote to get what I think he (and you) wants.  @pyfunc: Check the updated function.

Comment: @aaron: How does this do the opposite of what he wants? `bad` is an array of strings, `talk` is a string. He needs to check if the string is in the array of strings... makes sense. Not very robust, but it's a step in the right direction and should resolve the (run-time) errors which is what the op asked.

Comment: @Mark the old version tested if the whole input string was one of a set of words. The new version gets my +1 and tests correctly if any of a set of words is contained in the input string. pyfunc's example demonstrates the flaw with the old one.

Comment: @aaronmcsmooth: I was referring to the old version. It works, but only for one-word responses. Like I said, not robust, but it fixes the error the op was receiving. If we're arguing about the best way to write a chat bot... then all of these responses deserve -1 because they have a long ways to go ;)

Answer (score 0):

Use for loop and apply the same logic for 'good' too.

```
for badStr in bad:
    if badStr in talk:
       print "I'm sorry to hear that :("
       break

for goodStr in good:
    if goodStr in talk:
       print "That's good!"
       break
```

Comment: you could use `break` and `else` instead of the ugly flag ;)